# Show that every integer is the coefficient of some $\Phi_n(x)$

Tags: cyclotomic-polynomials

I know $\Phi_{105}(x)$ has a 2 and $\Phi_{210}(x)$ has a -2 as a coefficient

Comment: There is a short proof of this here: https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pja/1195513653